# Calling a SQL Agent Job from another Job on a remote server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, sql-agent

Is there a way to trigger a job on a from another job on a remote server  without using Linked Servers?

The reasoning is that the job being triggered executes an SSIS package on 2008.  The calling job resides on a 2005 server, so cannot execute the job directly.

The servers are not linked, and I was hoping there was a way to call one from the other.

Comment: Can you explain the situation? Does it not work if you try and execute it via a linked server or is there some reason why you don't want to create one?

Comment: I believe the servers are not linked because one db server is set aside to only communicate with a web server in the DMZ via non-standard ports.  The other is an internal db server.  I don't know if linked-servers would compromise this, but it wouldn't be my call, and I'd like to work around it if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the type "cmdexec (operating system)" in the SQL Agent and then use the dtexec \f "....." command line utily to execute SSIS 2008 package. This shud work !

Export the dtsx file to the 2005 server box and call the dtsx from command line using dtexec utility.

Comment: 2008 SSIS packages can't be executed in SQL Server 2005.  It sounds as if that is what you are suggesting.  Am I just mis-understanding?

Comment: You cannot do that only if you have a package that is SQL Server bound. You can execute the package from a file system. What i suggest is to export the dtsx files with it config files and then just like you execute them using the command line dtexec utitlity do it inside the Agent job step that has a type operating system (cmdexec). This shud work !

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will work. Create a http end point that calls sp_start_job

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181591.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The folllowing code should work, assuming you have authority execute xp_cmdshell.  Just need to replace text for @job_name and @server_name.

```
USE master 
GO 
-- To allow advanced options to be changed.
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1 
GO 
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE 
GO
-- To disable the feature.
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1 
GO 
-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE 
GO 


declare @retcode int 
declare @job_name varchar(300) 
declare @server_name varchar(200) 
declare @query varchar(8000) 
declare @cmd varchar(8000) 

set @job_name = 'hodes - grant user permissions' ------------------Job name goes here. 
set @server_name = 'msc-dbs04' ------------------Server name goes here. 

set @query = 'exec msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = ''' + @job_name + '''' 
set @cmd = 'osql -E -S ' + @server_name + ' -Q "' + @query + '"' 

print ' @job_name = ' +isnull(@job_name,'NULL @job_name') 
print ' @server_name = ' +isnull(@server_name,'NULL @server_name') 
print ' @query = ' +isnull(@query,'NULL @query') 
print ' @cmd = ' +isnull(@cmd,'NULL @cmd') 

exec @retcode = xp_cmdshell @cmd 

if @retcode <> 0 or @retcode is null 
begin 
print 'xp_cmdshell @retcode = '+isnull(convert(varchar(20),@retcode),'NULL @retcode') 
end 

USE MASTER
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
-- To disable the feature.
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
-- To do not allow advanced options to be changed.
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```